How to get the Item ID of running pipeline step in Sitecore DEF?
How to get the Item ID of running pipeline step during Sitecore DataExchange Framework job execution?

Please try the below steps

Create a Custom Processor Create a custom processor that extends the base DEF processor, e.g., Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.PipelineSteps.PipelineStepProcessor
Access the Pipeline Step Context You can get the PipelineStep object from the context and retrieve the Item ID using the following code:


using Sitecore.DataExchange.Contexts;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Models;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.PipelineSteps;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;

public class CustomPipelineStepProcessor : PipelineStepProcessor
{
    protected override void ProcessPipelineStep(
        PipelineStep pipelineStep, 
        PipelineContext pipelineContext, 
        ILogger logger)
    {
        // Ensure the pipeline step is valid
        if (pipelineStep == null)
        {
            logger.Error("The pipeline step is null. Processing skipped.");
            return;
        }

        // Get the Item ID of the pipeline step
        var itemId = pipelineStep.Identifier;

        // Log or use the Item ID
        logger.Info($"Executing pipeline step with Item ID: {itemId}");

        // Call the base implementation if required
        base.ProcessPipelineStep(pipelineStep, pipelineContext, logger);
    }
}


Hope this helps !!!

I am getting the error "pipelineStep doesn't contain a definition for StepDefinitionItemId."

Can you try using pipelineStep.Identifier

Thanks @Sreekrishnan
